# merging rotated pdf with non rotated pdf in python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, reportlab, pypdf

I am using python libraries `PyPDF2` and `reportlab` to add text fields into an existing PDF.
I currently use the function

```
def makeTextFields():

    packet = io.BytesIO()
    can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=landscape(letter))

    can.acroForm.textfield(name='fname', tooltip='First Name',
                    x=500, y=20, borderStyle='inset',
                    borderColor=blue, fillColor=blue, 
                    width=79, height=24,
                    textColor=black, forceBorder=False, annotationFlags ="")

    can.showPage()
    can.save()

    packet.seek(0)
    text_fields = PdfFileReader(packet)
    return text_fields
```

to create a PDF with the text fields then the following to load the base pdf, merge and save

```
main = PdfFileReader(open("master.pdf", 'rb'))
text_fields = makeTextFields()

output = PdfFileWriter()
text_field_page = text_fields.getPage(0)
page = main.getPage(0)

page.mergePage(text_field_page)

output.addPage(text_field_page)

stream = open("dest.pdf", "wb")
output.write(stream)
stream.close()
```

this solution would work fine however `master.pdf` has a rotation of `90` this means that when `page.mergePage` is called the text field pdf is automatically roated 90 degrees to match the base pdf and leaves the text fields 90 degrees with sideways text

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I have tried replacing `page.mergePage` with `page.mergeRotatedTranslatedPage` to no luck, I have also tried setting `annotationFlags ="norotate"` which according to reportlab docs should allow the text field to ignore canvas rotation but that did not work. lastly i tried

```
can.saveState()
can.rotate(90)
can.acroForm.textfield(name='fname', tooltip='First Name',
                    x=500, y=20, borderStyle='inset',
                    borderColor=blue, fillColor=blue, 
                    width=79, height=24,
                    textColor=black, forceBorder=False, annotationFlags ="")
can.restoreState()
```

in the hopes of rotating the text field 90 degrees offset of the page so it will be 0 when the page is rotated to 90 but that seemed to have no affect

I believe the solution will lie in either finding a way to nullify the rotation on the text field,
applying an initial rotation to the text field, or merging the two pdfs without matching the rotation. However, any other solutions / libraries are apreciated.

I am also open to creating the pdf in another program and just merging them using python. Or using a different language if python isnt the best language for the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

text_field_page.mergeRotatedTranslatedPage(page , -90, page .mediaBox.getWidth() / 2, page .mediaBox.getWidth() / 2)